# How to auto-transfer inbound call to an outside number in Asterisk?

Tags: asterisk

How to automatically transfer inbound call to an outside number in Asterisk server?

Example:

When a customer calls to a tollfree number it's connected to my call center server.

Here we have 3 options: `1` for English, `2` for Telugu and `3` for Hindi.
If the customer selects option `1`, they should be redirected to a dealer number.

If the customer selects option `2` it redirect to my private line. This option is working fine because this number is an internal number.

I'd like to know how to auto-transfer the inbound call to an outside number in Asterisk if customer selects option `2`?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a SIP gateway, you first need to register it in sip.conf

register => user:pass@gatewayip/number_from_gateway (so you can make outbound calls)

then for option 3 for example you can assign an internal number 103, and you can send the call to 103:

exten => 103,1,Dial(Local/EXTERNALNUMBERHERE,45,tr)

There are manuals online, and this can easily be found, with more examples. So please do your digging before asking here ;)